# No consigo convertir la fecha del json

Tags: python

Tengo un pequeño código en python que lo que intento esque me muestre la fecha pero no consigo que me la muestre, la fecha esta generada por una url en json:
está es la url:
https://images.habbo.com/habbo-web-news/es/production/front.json

y lo qué intento es obtener published con este pequeño código:

```
import time

time.ctime(int("1667300455000"))

print(time.strftime("%D %H:%M", time.localtime(int("1667300455000"))))
```

me tira el error:

```
time.ctime(int("1667300455000"))
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Pero no me la muestra

La fecha deberia de dar: **1 nov. 2022**

He probado en este sitio web:
https://www.unixtimestamp.com/

y si da el resultado

Comment: Y a mi me da `08/24/04 19:16` (sin errores)

Comment: a mi no me funciona, no se porque
https://i.imgur.com/R7DRYC5.png

Comment: Parece que es por la version de Python. En la 3.7.15 no me da error, pero en la 3.9.0 si. Una solución rápida es quitarle los 3 ceros del final, obtienes el resultado esperado `Nov 01 2022`